# How to have a new line for each row : When displaying a variable in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, sqlplus

I have a shell script having this command.

```
var=$(sqlplus a/a <<-EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
select * from table1;
exit
EOF
)
```

When I do a echo $var. It displays it in a single line with space separated.
I want each row from the output in a new line separation rather than space.

```
Sample Output : 1 2 3

I want: 
1
2
3
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Probably you meant to type `echo "$var"`. Without the quotes, all whitespace (including newlines) is turned into a single space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a stand alone test case for your problem:

```
$ cat script
var="1
2
3"

echo $var

$ bash script
1 2 3
```

This issue is both mentioned in the [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) list and caught by [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net):

```
$ shellcheck script
In script line 5:
echo $var
     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Working example:

```
$ cat script
var="1
2
3"

echo "$var"

$ bash script
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for tok in $var; do
    echo $tok
done
```